# class is not given its attributes. limit?(html + css)

Tags: html, css, class, limit

I have it set so that when I hover over a p tag it will being given the class highlight, which will highlight it. but when I do it it doesn't work. It already has a class, and when I get rid of that one it works. Can they only have one?

css is:

```
.selector {
background-color: transparent;
display: block;
width: 19%;
float: left;
}

.highlight {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blue;
color: red;
}
```

and html snippet:

```
<div class='selector'>
    <p class='sel_name'>Shows<p>
    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
        <li><a href=''>option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>option 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little more??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do highlight with css like this
http://jsfiddle.net/aWn3X/

I have added the following :

`.highlight, .sel_name:hover 
   {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blue;
color: red;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

have a look and tell me if that's anywhere near what you are trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/L5zfpjo3/

```
.selector {
background-color: transparent;
display: block;
width: 19%;
float: left;
}

.selector p:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px blue;
color: red;
}
```